# How to test IP address geolocation service

Tags: testing, geolocation, ip-geolocation

There is a IP address geolocation service that will tell the viewer city or country based on IP address. and we might set the default country on menu based on the result of this location service.

I wonder how can i test on this such as i am in Thailand but want to test it by stimulating Hongkong ip address so that i can see if that website provide proper feedback based on geolocation service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a socks proxy http://sockslist.net/.

Answer (score 1):

They way we're validating IP geolocations services is through [geoedge's proxy network](http://www.geoedge.com/). There are many more such networks out there, but we found that they have the highest geographical reach.