# Geolocation implementation in Opera

Tags: html, geolocation, opera, w3c-geolocation

I'm testing HTML5 geolocation.
I have some weird results in Opera and Opera Mobile.

When I visit the site after some time (for example 25 minutes) after the last visit position timestamp is from some time in the past. But I pass options telling that I want position not older then 5 seconds. After page refresh I get position timestamp close to 'now'. I think it should return position timestamp close to 'now' on every visit.

Example:

First visit: position time stamp 23:23:13

close browser:

return to site at 23:45:20: position timestamp 23:25:21

refresh: position timestamp 23:45:11

Here is my API call:

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, { maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true });`

You can observe this on azure website I created for test

[geotest.apphb.com](http://geotest.apphb.com/)

Edit:
Few minutes ago I learned that opera:config gives me access to geolocation settings among wich I found Send location request only on change.
When I turn it off geolocation api works as it's supposed to. But I don't understand this setting. What has to change in order to send location request?
With this setting turned on geolocation api gives me location from few hours ago. Even though I'm in different city already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Opera's config website for Windows](http://help.opera.com/operaconfig/versions/Windows/11.50/en/index.html), the *Send location request only on change* means the following:

> Only send location request if some of the data providers (Wi-Fi, cell, etc) actually changed.

So I am assuming that when you changed cities, you didn't change data providers as mentioned above.  If you were to find a Wi-Fi access point or use another technology to access the internet, it would probably send a location request and would be updated.

Comment: this might be it! do you know if I can renew bounty. I need time to check this.

Comment: @Peri Honestly, I don't know if you can renew a bounty.  I tried looking at [how the bounty system works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) but didn't find anything that extends it.  Also, you can probably [test this using a socks proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495855/how-to-test-ip-address-geolocation-service).

Comment: @BPaasch check out the [**What is automatic awarding?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). `Approximately twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.`

Comment: Ok you answered my question. Thanks. Congrats on your bounty! :) But still I don't understand what sense does that browser's behaviour make. If I change cities it should show new location. I don't understand how my cell provider can change.

Comment: @Peri  I agree, it is a very odd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As the page already loaded, `getCurrentPosition` assumes that the position you want is the position when the page has been loaded(the users current position on page load).

Use [`watchPosition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#watch-position) to update the position continuously(without page reload).

Comment: what do you mean by 'page already loaded' I can visit page few hours after previous visit and it still displays previous location- different city

Comment: well perhaps it gets cached, have you tried the WatchPosition(it accepts the same parameters)?

Comment: Yes it gets cached. That's the problem. It ignores my parameters { maximumAge: 5000 }